# How to compare property in object that is in localstorage? (React)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, compare, local-storage

I have object called newItem that has property called productOID. So I have an array that stores the same several objects. When I push it to array called productData I want to compare two productOIDs that is in localstorage and variables's. If they have the same productOID I want to restrict pushing it to array. Here's a code:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const productData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('looked-recently')) || []
    const newItem =
    {
        productImg: JSON.parse(this.props.data.getProduct.mediaUrl).images[0],
        productPrice: this.props.data.getProduct.minimalPrice,
        productName: this.props.data.getProduct.name,
        productOID: this.props.data.getProduct.oid
    }

    console.log(
        newItem.productOID ===
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('looked-recently'))
        .map(item => item.productOID)
    )

    productData.push(newItem)
    localStorage.setItem('looked-recently', JSON.stringify(productData.slice(productData[productData.length - 4], 5)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data= productData.map((products) =>{
  if(products.productOID!== newItem.productOID) 
      return products
  })
  data.map((datas)=>{
      if(datas){
          productData.push(datas)
      }
  })
```

replace this code